# Future tenses difference in meaning

Tags: future-tense

please confirm if I am right regarding the difference in the meaning of the following variants:

1)- Is Jenny going to find…
2)- Isn’t  Jenny going to find…
3)- Will Jenny find…
4)- Won’t  Jenny find a job easily when she graduates?

1) asking for an opinion about the prediction based on some present evidences

2) even stronger assurance (through negative form -sarcasm)that Jenny will find the job for sure.

3)prediction of the future event (ambiguous future, no facts, just asking..)

4)through negative we doubt somehow and ask if there may be some obstacles in the future for finding a job. Or vice versa: we are sure she should find a job.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples can be divided into two pairs.

**Is Jenny going to find...** and **will Jenny find** are two ways of asking the same question. One or the other may be preferred in a particular context. There is no difference in meaning.

The same is true for the two negative questions, **Isn't Jenny going to find...** and **won't Jenny find**?

The first pair is used just to seek information. Neither points towards ambiguity or the presence or absence of facts as you suggest.

The second pair is typical of the construction we use when we suspect that some action may have a negative consequence:

> Won't someone slip on the stairs if you oil them now?

- or in response to a statement.

> A: The weak economy means that a lot of young people are unemployed.
>
> B: (Yes, but) won't Jenny (Isn't Jenny going to) find a job (easily) when she graduates.

Once again, there is no real distinction between the two constructions. They are completely interchangeable.

Comment: The second pair of questions is used when the underlying assumption is that the answer is affirmative (the expected answer is that yes, she will/is going to find a job; the alternative is possible but would be somewhat surprising).